# How do you install MySQL on a Google Compute Engine server?

Tags: mysql, firewall, google-cloud-platform

I've recently been trying to set up a compute engine instance that will host a SQL database for one of my projects. Issue is, every time I set up an instance and get everything installed, the port I open in Google's firewall is still closed and I cannot connect externally to my SQL server.

So far, I've done the following things and they've resulted in failure:

1. Use `mysql-server` instead of `mariadb-server`
2. Use Debian 8 instead of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
3. Create instance allowing all ingress traffic

All of these result in `nmap` showing the port as `closed` (as well as ports 80 and 443, which I allowed at the instance's creation) and a MySQL client on my local computer is unable to connect to the server.

I have disabled `ufw` each time, so it shouldn't be causing any issues.

Comment: 1 and 2 sound like random flailing - why did you try those? Is your MySQL install configured to listen to external connections via `bind-address`? Are you able to use MySQL locally from the instance? Is MySQL running?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yep, the server's running and I can connect with the `mysql` command. I have placed `bind = 0.0.0.0` in `my.cnf`. I tried those precisely for the reason you've said: random flailing. Me and a coworker have been trying to get this to work for hours, so we've tried everything we can think of.

Comment: Can you share your MySQL config and a screenshot of the Google firewall config?

Comment: Did you try opening the Google Cloud firewall? check this documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-firewalls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue - Zeb and I are working together. It wasn't an issue with GCP at all, it was `mysql` denying the connection because `bind-address` was set to `127.0.0.1` by default in the config located at `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on`
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0 
# 127.0.0.1 previously, changed to allow remote connections
```

After changing that in the config, `mysql` was listening on `0.0.0.0:3306` as shown by `netstat -plutn`.

You then need to add a remote user with access, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684341/3397688) post explains it perfectly.

Took a lot of digging, so hopefully this clears it up for anyone else who runs across this issue.